# Pass database data to several divs from one loop with php and laravel

Tags: php, html, laravel, sass

I have a paging setup, which can be shown as such:

```
<div class="page__A4">
</div>
<div class="page__A4">
</div>
<div class="page__A4">
</div>
```

Data is then passed from my SQL database using PHP, through a for loop, e.g:

```
@foreach($data as $value)
<div class="element">
    {{$value}}
</div>
@endforeach
```

which would leave the final markup:

```
<div class="page__A4">
   @foreach($data as $value)
    <div class="element">
        {{$value}}
    </div>
    @endforeach
</div>
<div class="page__A4">
</div>
<div class="page__A4">
</div>
```

My `$value` is dynamic in height, and when the amount of `$value`'s exceeds the first `page__A4` element in height, I want it to proceed to the next page.

The real issue relies in that I am unable to use Javascript. I need to print these pages to PDF, which is done by combining a laravel view with a SASS styling file - meaning javascript wont be loaded in my final printed product.

Is there a way to achieve this, using a combination of laravel/php/SASS?

Answer (score 0):

You have to class="A_4" dynamic too if you want to use it in javascript.

```
foreach($values as $ value){
   <div class="'example'.$value.">
   </div> 

}
```

Comment: As mentioned I want to achieve this without JavaScript, as to make it function with my PDF printing requirements.